# Formik and Semanic UI React. Delay on typing, unnecessary validation

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react, formik

Here is a simple example of my dynamic form.

```
<Form.Group widths='equal'>
                    <Form.Input onChange={props.handleChange} fluid name={`${type}.${participant.number}.firstName`}
                                label={FIRST_NAME}
                                placeholder={FIRST_NAME_MODEL_DESCR}/>
                    <Form.Input onChange={props.handleChange} fluid label={LAST_NAME}
                                name={`${type}.${participant.number}.lastName`}
                                placeholder={LAST_NAME_MODEL_DESCR}/>
       </Form.Group>
```

in the Fromik itself i have simple console.log

```
    validate={values => {
        console.log(values);
    }}
```

So on every time when i'm typing into field, on every key press i'm getting log results from validation (which i don't want) and it has micro delay, on every key press down.

Comment: Well, you put in input fields onChange function. That is the reason why is it happening. What would you like to achieve?

Comment: how else could i get the value of input field? this "handleChange" is a Formik function. I would like to have all my values validated on submit only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass validateOnChange (and validateOnBlur if you want to disable that too) with a value of false to the Formik component (https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#validateonchange-boolean)

Comment: Still the whole form is rerendering when i'm typing into field. For change i'm using handleChange.

Comment: Yeah, it does because Formik holds the state of your form and the rest of your form is a child, and when a parent component re-renders, so does all of it's children unless shouldComponentUpdate returns false somewhere in the component tree. So if you need to prevent part of your form from re-rendering (usually isn't necessary unless you have a larger form), split your form fields out into separate components and use PureComponent to prevent components whose props don't change from re-rendering.

Comment: Hi @TLadd, can you tell me or show an example of how to do that? I'm having the same problem with slowness because of re-renders using `<Formik>` -> `<Form>` -> `<Field>`

Comment: @GuilhermeMoretto The Formik docs detail how to deal with performance problems using FastField https://formik.org/docs/api/fastfield. I'd give this a read.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to validate your fields on submit only, and since you are using Semantic-UI-React's Form component, I suggest using onSubmit handler function that Semantic is offering.

```
<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <Form.Group>
    <Form.Input placeholder='Name' name='name' value={name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
    <Form.Input
      placeholder='Email'
      name='email'
      value={email}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
    />
    <Form.Button content='Submit' />
  </Form.Group>
</Form>
```

With this to set your input value to the state `handleChange = (e, { name, value }) => this.setState({ [name]: value })`

And you can use this function to handle with formic your data validation

```
  handleSubmit = () => {
    const { name, email } = this.state

    // here you can use formic to validate name and email
  }
```